# Selecting random entry from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select a single random entry from a MySQL database using PHP?

I want to select the Author, AuthorText, and Date?

Comment: Multiple people have suggested using `order by rand()`, it's fine, but keep in mind that it's a performance killer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT Author, AuthorText, Date FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Double check your code, it's probaly a variable typo in one of your MySQL functions or queries. Or try it without the field Date. That might give some problems because of predefined function names in MySQL BTW, if you need better performance, check out this post http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to this interesting article:
[“Do not use ORDER BY RAND()” or “How to get random rows from table?”](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/)

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

will sort all the rows in the table, which can be extremely slow.

Better solution : say your table has the usual primary key auto-increment field, generate a rendom number between min(id) and max(id) and select the closest id.

It will not be as random as a "true" random selection, because a id after a large hole of deleted ids will have a higher probability of being chosen. But it will take 50 µs instead of 2 seconds if your table is large...

```
SET @t = (SELECT FLOOR(a + (b-a)*rand()) FROM (SELECT min(id) as a, max(id) as b FROM table)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id>@t ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by a random & restrict to 1 row as follows:

```
select 
  author, authortext, date 
from bookstable 
order by rand()
limit 1
```