# How do I insert images like this website in my website?

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of this website: http://8tracks.com/pitchfork/the-year-in-music-2012-the-top-100-tracks-of-2012 but I'm not sure how I'd go about displaying images on the website like they do. How would I display images as links like this website does? More specifically, how could I display different links each time the webpage is refreshed?

Sorry if I'm being vague, I'd more or less just like to know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't ask users to reverse-engineer external sites. Please post an example as part of your question: code or screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I display images as links like this website does?

Images as links are just links containing images:

```
<a href="..."><img src="..." alt="..."></a>
```

> More specifically, how could I display different links each time the webpage is refreshed?

Generate the HTML from a server side program (written in your programming language of choice). Have it select images at random. You could track them in a database and then use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921327/selecting-random-entry-from-mysql-database) to pick one (or more).